# Am I let go or are they anticipating my resignation?

Tags: resignation, termination

My boss gave me her decision last week, which is terminating my contract.

However, something is hindering her decision from upper management, especially that I didn't apply for the job, and I had to relocate.

Moreover, my boss is famous for being bad at retaining permanent contract employees.

Since this procedure of terminating me was triggered, she became distant and started marginalizing me again.

This morning, I went to work with a bag, as I was expecting a formal letter about the end of my contract this month.

I was nervously expecting that damn notification to get that famous letter.

(She submitted the formal decision of terminating me on Tuesday, and the guy who is supposed to do paperwork was supposed to contact me today).

Instead, my boss came and started asking about my tasks that I finished long ago but she didn't prioritise them.

I suspected that my behavior of keeping it secret and not telling anything negative about my boss + finishing and pushing some of work to remote repository made upper management change their mind (I was being loyal despite the bad news).

My boss started involving me again ...

When I spoke to HR last week, they told me they (the whole HR personnel) were shocked about her unfair decision, and I should urgently start looking.

I told them I was interviewing.

My boss seemed undecided over the last three months. Sometimes she became nice and started giving me hope, and some other times, she would go off and become hostile.

Is there a decision from upper management to cancel my termination or is my fate sealed?

Comment: Your manager, "the guy who is supposed to do paperwork" (?) or HR are the only people who can answer this question. Although I'd recommend looking for a new job either way, because being told you're terminated is not a particularly good sign (although if this delay has anything to do with upper management wanting to keep you, there's a chance you'll find yourself with a new manager in the near future). Usually they'd only tell you they're terminating you after the decision has been finalised, and that would indicate the start of your notice period (if any).

Comment: Regardless of what the company's official position ends up being, would you still want to work for management as wishy-washy as this? This seems highly unprofessional to me.

Comment: You should really be asking this question to the decision-makers at your company, not strangers on the internet. We have no way of knowing what they are really doing.

Answer (score 11):

**Short answer:** Unless someone tells you otherwise, then your contract is indeed terminated and you need to look for alternative employment.

So far all you have is your direct manager informing you that your contract will be terminated.  Despite any umming and ahhing by HR, unless they have given you any sort of real, tangible indication that the original decision by your manager has been rescinded, then it hasn't.

I would really not recommend waiting for a Hail Mary here.  Speak to HR if you believe your dismissal is unfair, but look as hard as you can for another role.  Unless you get notified by someone with the authority to notify you otherwise, your contract will end when specified by your manager.

Comment: *Unless someone tells you otherwise, then your contract is indeed terminated and you need to look for alternative employment.*  Time to find a new gig...

Answer (score 3):

Nobody knows. Your position is not safe, but you are only terminated when you get this in writing from HR. Never quit, unless you signed a contract with a better company.

What you should do is look for a better position without telling your company. And realise that your direct supervisor is the problem, not the rest of the company. So if she does anything, go straight to HR and complain. That’s usually not what you do, but the company seems to have figured out that she causes problems, so piling up complaints against her will help you case.

Answer (score 1):

Your boss (or soon-to-be-ex-boss) is a jerk and is not going to change.

This looks like a power trip short-circuited by their bosses, who already know far too well about their reputation as a bad boss.  Also, this looks like constructive dismissal on top of it - the effort to push an employee out by making their work environment impossible, and is trying to get you to resign so you can't receive unemployment benefits.

Contact the company or employment agency that sent you for this long-term contract and tell them what's going on.  If this bosses' reputation with permanent contract employees is as atrocious as you're saying, your company will cancel its contract with the company and alert other employment agencies not to send other employees there.

In the meantime, continue looking for a new job.  Your new boss will be nowhere near as bad as the one you have now.

Answer (score -1):

Only upper management (and very possibly your boss) knows the answer to that but I think it would be very wise to start looking anyway just in case they do decide to surprise you one day.